# Access export file Missing wizzard

Tags: ms-access, export, wizard

Access 2010  - Export query to text or Excel.
 Missing wizard.
 One of my Access apps has a window with buttons with VBA Do.
Cmd to export queries to Text or Excel which works.
 I have created a new App using the same database from scratch and imported the window. 
Now I get the error

> "Specification does not exist"

Previously I just ran the export manually and a wizard appeared to allow me to save the specification. 
Now when exporting manually no wizard appears. 
I have researched and only found a suggestion that the accwiz.dll is required.
 Microsoft do not have it available for download. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While importing the objects to the new database, click "Options" and select *Import/Export Specs* (3rd option).

The export specification will then be available.

[image]